# Построить свой маршрут не по дорогам (Я.карты)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Я сам могу задать точки для маршрута, пробовал через viaIndexes, но всё равно строится не по ним, а по куску дороги, о которой знает яндекс.
Вот, например, смешной маршрут между [этими двумя точками](https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=39.970432%2C52.378005&mode=routes&rtext=52.371262%2C39.955489~52.379598%2C39.970454&rtm=atm&z=14.8): [52.371262, 39.955489],[52.379598, 39.970454].
Как построить трек по заданной мной траектории?

*В апи яндекса отправляют с вопросами сюда. Надеюсь, не оффтоп.

Comment: Есть примеры как пробовали делать?

Comment: Ну вот это сделано было через штатный мультирут с транзитными точками. Сейчас сделал трек тупо отрезками, но мне это не нравится, конечно.

Comment: Сервис построения маршрутов в API, конечно, строит маршрут по дорогам (автомобильным, пешеходным или со знанием об общественном транспорте). В этом его задача собственно и состоит. Если "маршрут не по дорогам" это просто соединить точки по прямой, рисуйте полилинию средствами API.

Comment: Вопрос, скорее, сводится к тому, может ли яндекс соединять точки хотя бы прямым отрезком, когда не видит между ними дороги? Иначе подобный примеру тупизм наблюдается в любой российской глухомани.
Мне трек отрезками рисовать подходит, но хуже. Ищу вариант комбинации с дорогами.